# Convert lambda with any | contains to expression tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees

How can the following simple lambda be represented using Expression Tree syntax?

```
v.Tags.Any(t => searchTags.Contains(t.ID));
```

Where :

- searchTags = List of long
- v = Class with Tags navigational property
- t = Tag class with ID property

Variations on the following have been tried:

```
 var anyInfo = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
         .Where(m => m.Name == "Any")
         .Single(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
         .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Tag));


 var toQueryable = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
         .Where(m => m.Name == "AsQueryable")
         .Single(m => m.IsGenericMethod)
         .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Tag));

 var containsInfo = typeof(List<long>).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(long) });

 var list = Expression.Constant(searchTags);
 var mcvalue = Expression.Property(v, "Tags");
 ParameterExpression tagParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Tag), "mt");

 var tagID = Expression.Property(tagParam, "ID");
 var st = Expression.Call(list, containsInfo, tagID);
 return Expression.Call(null, anyInfo, Expression.Call(null, toQueryable, mcvalue), st);
```

Comment: Tip: if you declare a variable such as `Expression<Func<T, bool>> temp = x => x.Tags.Any(...);` and place a breakpoint after it, you should be able to inspect it in your IDE and review the `DebugView` debugger property on `temp` to see roughly how the expression gets constructed. You should then (hopefully) be able to construct it manually

Comment: [TIP] My advice is to not build these types of expressions with the expression api. It will result in hard to maintain code. Use a library like linqkit to combine expressions that the compiler generated for you

Comment: @MBoros Libraries are great once you already know what you're doing but just don't want to do it every time. Clearly, in this instance, I don't completely understand what i'm doing. Until I do, I don't want to black box it and also don't want to take a dependency on a library for what will actually only be a half dozen methods of search related expressions. Frankly I should already know how to do this but for whatever reason don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the C# equivalent of the result of your `return` statement:

```
v.Tags.AsQueryable().Any(searchTags.Contains(t.ID))
```

Aside from the redundant `AsQueryable()` call, the main issue is that neither the result, nor the `Any` call argument are *lambda* expressions, but expressions representing a potential lambda expression *body*. In order to convert them to lambda expressions (and connect with the associated parameter expressions), you need to use one of the [`Expression.Lambda`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda(v=vs.110).aspx) method overloads.

So building lambda expression like

```
v => v.Tags.Any(t => searchTags.Contains(t.ID));
```

could be done with something like this:

```
static Expression<Func<T, bool>> SampleLambda<T>(List<long> searchTags)
{
    var v = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "v");

    var t = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Tag), "t");

    var containsCall = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new [] { typeof(long) },
        Expression.Constant(searchTags),
        Expression.Property(t, "ID")
    );

    var anyCall = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new [] { typeof(Tag) },
        Expression.Property(v, "Tags"),
        Expression.Lambda(containsCall, t)
    );

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(anyCall, v);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried doing that earlier on but it appears to limit my ability to further compose a query when returning an 'Expression<Func' The above is just a piece of the query which will be further combined with phrase criteria etc. 'Expression.And(a,b)' I do convert to an 'Expression<Func' at the very end but didn;t think I should be doing that for each 'piece'

Comment: If you need just the `Any` part, simply take (return) the `anyCall` variable. However the inner `Expression.Lambda` is required, which is the essential part of the answer.

Comment: O.k. brilliant. I've reread what you have posted and applied accordingly and it works perfectly. A nicely simplified version of what I was trying to achieve. Thanks so much... i learnt something here.